# How to set up thesaurus in TexStudio?

Tags: texstudio

I have been able to set up the dictionary in TeXstudio, however, when I ask for Thesaurus, it tells me Thesaurus database not found.

Can anyone please help?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is guess you're on Ubuntu? How did you install TeXstudio? Did you fetch the optional dependencies?

Comment: If I remember correctly, I downloaded and ran the debian file.

Comment: @Troy I've already retracted the flag and forgot the auto-generated comment.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**A tiny note:**

I did this on Windows, but I don't see this being much different for whichever OS you are using (Ubuntu, from the comments?). Also for the record, this is on TeXstudio 2.12.6 (hg 6632:7777b2b8a906).

This solution is largely inspired by another one from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28235871/8421052), but I will supplement this with pictures, and to provide an answer here in TeX.SE. Hopefully this will be sufficient and clear enough to answer future questions about thesauruses in TeXstudio.

---

With that out of the way,

**Step 1.** Obtain the database files for the thesaurus of your desired language. Admittedly, this might be the harder step of the two due to the lack of thesaurus databases out there. TeXstudio suggests two sites to look at (these links are clickable from within TeXstudio's options as well):

- [OpenOffice](https://extensions.openoffice.org/de/search?f[0]=field_project_tags%3A157)
- [LibreOffice](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions?getCategories=Dictionary&getCompatibility=any)

If you already have a database (`.dat` file), then skip ahead to Step 2. *If you can't find one in your language, I don't think there's much you can do except to create the database yourself?*

Here I provide an example for English. As of August 2017, it seems that the most updated English database is one from LibreOffice, found [here](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/english-dictionaries), last updated Jul 2017. (The official project website can be found [here](http://marcoagpinto.cidadevirtual.pt/proofingtoolgui.html).)

[image: oxt]

*(Yes, it does say that it is a dictionary, but it works fine as a thesaurus as well.)*

Go ahead and download the `.oxt` file. If you extract this `.oxt` file, using 7Zip or the likes, you should see a `th_en_US_v2.dat` and `th_en_US_v2.idx` file.

[image: extract]

**Step 2.** Copy the `.dat` and `.idx` files to a convenient folder for you. I would recommend placing it in a folder named `thesaurus` within your TeXstudio folder, (for Windows)

```
~\AppData\Roaming\TeXstudio\thesaurus
```

To find this directory quickly, you can try these steps:

**Step 2a.** Under TeXstudio options, navigate to:

```
Configure TeXstudio -> Language Checking -> 'Spell Check' section
```

and see the directory for your `Spelling Dictionary Directories` (indicated by the longer red box). By default, this should link you to a `dictionaries` folder within your TeXstudio parent folder.

[image: folder]

The end result should be the `.dat` and `.idx` files being in a particular folder (the `texstudio\thesaurus` folder, in my case).

[image: folder 2]

**Step 3.** The final step is to copy the *directory* of the thesaurus `.dat` file and paste into the `Thesaurus Database` entry in the TeXstudio options. Another (quicker) way is to click the icon (indicated by the small black box) in the above picture, and navigate to the folder containing the thesaurus files.
Choose the `.dat` file, click <kbd>ok</kbd> and you're done!

**Step 4.** If you set everything up correctly, then it should work when you give it a test. See the following:

Right clicking on the word (in this case, `happy`) that you want to search the thesaurus for:

[image: 4a]

and getting a window that pops up:

[image: 4b]

An alternative (default) keyboard shortcut for this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>, which opens up the same thesaurus window for the word your cursor is currently sitting on.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly for me on Ubuntu. :)

Comment: @Troy, How can I make it work in Texworks? I have downloaded the thesaurus files from your link, but I am stuck at step 3 and step 2 for finding a way to add thesaurus directory in Texworks (in your case it is Texstudio).

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 2020, the solution was pretty simple for a US thesaurus:

```
$ sudo apt install mythes-en-us
```

TeXStudio finds the thesaurus automatically if you restart it.
To search for other languages:

```
$ apt search mythes
```