# Thesaurus databases for TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, editors

I am looking for English Thesaurus databases to add to my TexStudio environment. Can you please direct me where can I find such thing? Which dictionary should I take from [OpenOffice](https://extensions.openoffice.org/de/search?f[0]=field_project_tags%3A157) or [LibreOffice](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions?getCategories=Dictionary&getCompatibility=any) so I will be able to [ctrl+shift+F8](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION114) on words and see its synonymous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest one I was able to find was from [LibreOffice](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/english-dictionaries), last updated Jan 2017. It does say that it is a dictionary, but I find it works fine as a thesaurus as well.

For example, the word `happy` gives this:

[image: happy]

---

If you would like to know how to make the thesaurus work in TeXstudio, see my other answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387327/117534). (Your question only asked about where to obtain such a thesaurus file).

Answer (score 0):

To preciseley answer your question, see Troys answer, but i think you have the english database preinstalled. Like the french and italien aswell.
To simply pick the database go
*Configure TeXstudio -> Language Checking -> 'Spell Check' section*.

[image]

Click the Thesaurus Database folder and pick the desired language. th_en_US_v2 in your case.

[image]