# (TeXstudio) Ignore specific words in grammar check

Tags: texstudio, spelling, grammar

I am new to the community and I have a question about the grammar check in TeXstudio. As we know, some words are not recognized by the grammar checker, e.g., binarization. I am not very comfortable when the red underlines keep popping up. Also, in this case, we might actually have misspelling problems.

My question is that if there is a way to ignore some specific words such that these underlines could disappear. Some people say I should find `.ign` file and add the words into the file. However, I could not find this file in the dictionaries.

Comment: Right click on the word, and "Add to dictionary"? As for the `.ign` file, it is in `%appdata%/TeXstudio/dictionaries`

Comment: (see step 2a in [How to set up thesaurus in TexStudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387327/117534) for a picture of where the dictionary files are.

Comment: @Troy The .ign should be there but it is not. I do not know why it is not there.

Comment: Ok, what about my first suggestion? Did you try that?

Comment: The path is found. The .ign file is not there or it is somehow covered. I try showing the hidden files. It is still not there.

Comment: No I mean the `add to dictionary` part. Or maybe I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I was referring to adding the words to the .ign file.

Comment: your main question was “How to ignore some specific words so the lines could disappear”. It can be achieved by adding words to the dictionary from within TXS: why must you do it via the .ign file?

Comment: Modifying the .ign file is just one solution. Of course, everything is helpful as long as it ignore some specific words in the grammar check. But what do you mean by adding words to the dictionary from within TXS? Could you please provide some more specific instructions? Thank you.

Comment: Just right-click on the wrong-grammar word, e.g.`binarization`, and select `Add to dictionary` in the context menu. https://imgur.com/a/R8INBNr

Comment: The reason you don't have an `.ign` file is simply because you haven't added any words for the dictionary to ignore yet. If the above suggestion fails (it shouldn't), just create your own `en_GB.ign` (or whatever `<language>.ign`), open it in Notepad, type in `binarization`, and save. Then restart TXS.

Comment: Now it works! @Troy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. The most straightforward way is to right-click the wrong-grammar word, e.g. `binarization`, and select Add to dictionary in the context menu.

[image]

2. The other thing you can do is to manually add the wrong-grammar word, e.g. `binarization` to the list of ignored words stored in the `.ign` file (should be in the folder `%AppData%/Roaming/TeXstudio/dictionaries` -- see step 2a in [How to set up thesaurus in TexStudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387327/117534) for more details).

   In your case, since you don't have an `.ign` file, you can just create one yourself. Start up a new text file (in Notepad, TeXstudio etc.), type in `binarization`, and then save as `<language>.ign`. For example, `en_GB.ign`. If you have more than 1 word to ignore, place each new word on a new line. Restart TXS and now the dictionary should ignore the words inside the `.ign` file.